# JUnit エラーの対処法がわからない

Tags: junit

JUnit を実行したらエラーが出てしまいましたが、"cause by" からを読んでも理由がわからないのですが、どうしたらいいか教えていただきたいです。

```
@Test
public void 01(){
    assertEquals(null, target.encode(null));
}
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
caused by: java.langIllegalStateException: Neither GenericXmlContextLoader nor AnnotationConfigContextLoader was able to load an ApplicationContext from [MergedConfiguration@63a5d002 testClass = Test, locations ='{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '{}',
propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]].
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testingの際に、ビーンの内容を知る必要があるので、アノテーションを使います。`＠ContextConfiguration`を使って見て下さい。これを使わないと、xmlファイルが見つからないとかでビーンの内容が無の状態なのでエラーが出ます。

これを参考にしてみてください：

```
package com.javarticles.spring;
 
public class BeanA {
 
}
```

空っぽのビーンを`SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class`を使って走らせます:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
 
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
 
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class SpringContextConfigurationExample {
    @Autowired
    private BeanA beanA;
     
    @Test
    public void beanAExists() {
        assertNotNull(beanA);
    }
}
```

この場合はクラス名が`SpringContextConfigurationExample.class`なので、XMLファイル名は、`SpringContextConfigurationExample-context.xml`にして下さい。

詳しくは、公式[ドキュメント](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing)を見れくれると助かります。他にも、単純に`@ContextConfiguration`に関してググると手っ取り早いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！junitは作ったクラスに対してSpringContextConfigurationExample.classとSpringContextConfigurationExample-context.xmlクラスの計３つがjunitを動かすためには必要ということでしょうか？